# Print 500 time string with concatated unique random number in text file in C

Tags: c

i want to write code that will print 500 line with this string:

```
if(strstr(""token: XXXXXXXXXX"", token_read)){ token_num = X; }
```

So XXXXXXXXXX must be a unique (non-repeated) random number, and X must be number incremented by 1. And text file will be look like this:

```
if(strstr(""token: 1312312412"", token_read)){ token_num = 1; }
if(strstr(""token: 5829572542"", token_read)){ token_num = 2; }
```

etc.

But my code don't working, and if it would work code don't generate a unique numbers. So in double-array must be 500**x**10 random numbers

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char x[500][11];
    char b[100];
    int a, z;
    for(z = 0; z < 499; z++){
        x[z] = rand(10);
    }
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("a.txt", "rb+");
    if(fptr == NULL){
        fptr = fopen("a.txt", "wb");
        if (fptr == NULL)
            return -1;
        else
            for(a = 2; a < 500; a++){
                snprintf(b, sizeof(b), "if(strstr(""token: %d"", token_read)){ token_num = a; }", x[a])
                fputs(b, fptr);
            }
    }
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

And sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Simple question is where is it failing and what is it doing when you run it in a debugger - also what is the current output?  Finally, what compiler warning are being generated as they will give you some hints as well.

Comment: To start with, I know warnings will be generated on your first for loop about type assignment.  What do you think `rand(10)` does?  Right now it generates 1 weird ASCII character or a `NUL` character per string - not 10 characters like you may think.  And it doesn't assign it like you think either.

Comment: I think that rand(10) will generate 10 random numbers.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand

Comment: This could should not even compile.  Ok, new step 1, try actually compiling your code and fix the syntax errors.

Comment: You don't use `""` to embed quotes inside a string, you escape it with `\"`

Comment: I can't run debugging, because code isn't want to compile. So if I use propely this function, still numbers don't be unique...

Comment: @Barmar But `""` is same as `\"` in GNU Compiler.

Comment: You can't assign to arrays in C, so you can't assign to `x[z]`. If you want to copy a string, you use `strcpy()`. But `rand()` doesn't return a string, it returns a single number.

Comment: @SebastianBiegański I can't find any documentation of that extension in the GCC manual. Do you have a reference?

Comment: @Barmar - stop.  This code won't compile as-is.  OP needs to go back to hello world and start from there.  The assumption on `rand()` means there has been no research into functions.  The assignment across array type means there is no knowledge yet here either.  OP, please re-review arrays, strings, and other uses and hopefully get some help from your professor if you are in a class.

Comment: @Barmar Because i want to make 5000 random numbers (rows cannot duplicate) in double-array in this loop. Just like that:

1 row`3 9 2 6 2 6 3 3 2 1`
2 row `7 8 1 3 6 1 3 5 6 2`

Comment: Please tell me you are not attempting to write production level hashing code and that this is an assignment?

Comment: If you want 5000 random numbers you need to call `rand()` 5000 times, not 500 times. Why do you think `rand(10)` returns 10 random numbers? You seem to be programming by guessing what things do, not by actually learning the language and reading documentation.

Comment: I want to make my own game anti-cheatengine system.

Comment: @Barmar Look i have a[5][5] array:
a[0] - return: ABCD(NULL)
a[0][0] - return: A

Comment: @MichaelDorgan He using CheatEngine, huh.

Comment: @Barmar In C language double-array is not the same as double-array in JavaScript, remember.

Comment: @SebastianBiegański That's correct. C has true 2-dimensional arrays, while in JavaScript they're just arrays of arrays, similar to pointer arrays in C.

Comment: That's why you can't assign to `x[z]`, because it's an array and arrays can't be assigned to.

Comment: Look: https://imgur.com/Zz8gC6W

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before this post closes and for giving me such entertainment, here is a small piece of your puzzle that is missing

```
char x[500][11];
char b[100];
int a, z, i;
for(z = 0; z < 500; z++)
{
    for(i=0; i<10;i++)
    {
        x[z][i] = '0' + rand() % 10;
    }
    x[z][10] = '\0';
    printf("%s \n", x[z]);
}
```

This does not check for uniqueness.  You will have to figure that out along with everything else.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to change the world with my new anti-cheat system.